# Mat-icon: when pressing a button all the icons change

Tags: angular, angular-material, materialbutton

I'm using Mat-card to display a list using an array and *ngFor and when pressed on the button, it will change the icon (mat-icon) only on the selected card but it changes for all the buttons in the list.

here's an example:

[image]
it's before pressing on the button and the condition to change the icon is false

[image]

but when I press it all the icons change.

here's my code:

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let a of items ;let i = index" class="item-card mat-card">

        <mat-card-header class="card-mat-header" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <div class="card-mat-header-text"></div>

          <mat-card-title class="card-mat-title">{{a.name}}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Price :{{a.price}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <div class="img-wrapper">      
            <img class="mat-card-image"  src={{a.image}} alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">

        </div>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            {{a.desc}}
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>

        <mat-card-actions class="right-button" >
          <button  mat-button class="mat-button mat-button-base" (click)="itemStatus(i)" > 
            <mat-icon>{{iconName}}</mat-icon>{{itemStatis}} {{a.addedToCart}}
          </button>

        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
```

also the used function:

```
  itemStatus(i){

      this.items[i].addedToCart =  !this.items[i].addedToCart
      if(this.items[i].addedToCart)
      {
        this.iconName = "shopping_cart";
        this.itemStatis= "Added";
      }
      else{
        this.iconName = "add_shopping_cart";
        this.itemStatis= "Add To Cart";
      }
    }
```

please if anyone is familiar with this kind of mistake help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maintaining the  `iconName` and `itemStatis` at component level **not** at the `item` level

Check the Example below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-moun8k

**In XComponent.ts change `itemStatus` to**

```
itemStatus(i){
  this.items[i].addedToCart =  !this.items[i].addedToCart
}
```

**In HTML change Button section to**

```
<button  mat-button class="mat-button mat-button-base" (click)="itemStatus(i)" > 
  <mat-icon>{{a.addedToCart ? 'shopping_cart' : 'add_shopping_cart'}}</mat-icon>
    {{a.addedToCart ? 'Added' : 'Add To Cart'}} 
</button>
```

Comment: In the Html file? But it's inside the *ngfor Loop ?

Comment: I am creating a sample, give me 5 mins

Comment: Thank you it did work I've never worked with this method before.

Comment: Happy to help, In html, the content inside `{{ }}` is context aware and evaluateable